# How to properly send an int over serial communication

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to control a servomotor using python and arduino over serial communication but i cannot seem to find out how to send the int value over to arduino. (cannot convert to string because str function does not support unicode).

The code opens a window with x and y axis and prints the coordonates to the screen. They are both int types. How can I send them to arduino to move the servo?

```
import serial
import time
import pygame

port = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate=9600)
time.sleep(1)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 540, 540
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


Color = (255,255,255)


def main():
        run = True
        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
                #get position x,y mouse
                x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                #Draw y line
                pygame.draw.line(WIN, Color, (0, y), (WIDTH,y)) 
                #Draw x line
                pygame.draw.line(WIN, Color, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT)) 
                #Draw circle
                pygame.draw.circle(WIN, (139,0,0), (x, y), 5, 0)
                pygame.display.flip()
                print(x,y)

                WIN.fill([0,0,0])
                time.sleep(0.15)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and this arduino code

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
int x;
void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    x = Serial.read();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you meant by "cannot convert to string because str function does not support unicode".

Comment: What could Unicode support have to do with this?  `str___` all support the ASCII codes.

Comment: TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '476'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting it into bytes before sending

`msg = bytes('1', 'utf-8')`

Convert that to int after receiving

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert an integer to a bytearray like so

```
ba = bytearray(struct.pack("i", num))
```

And then send the bytearray over serial

```
ser.write(ba)
```

On the arduino side you now read the bytes and "build" the int data type.

Comment: I will look into this as well. Thank you for your answer